# How to add a border and background color to bootstrap row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap Twitter (version 3.1.1) in my project. The section that I'm working on requires the row to have a border and background color. I'm wondering what is the best way to add these css properties. Here is example of my HTML structure:

```
<div class="container" id="container_profile">
    <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-6">Record ID: <strong>8734573</strong></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                 <div class="pull-right">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="validated" value="yes" />
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding another inner div wrapping both col-xs-6 div's. I used div `alert alert-warning` but that added some weird padding. What is the proper way to add style to existing bootstrap rows?

Answer (score 1):

The structure should be:

```
<div class="container" id="container_profile">
    <div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
     <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-6">Record ID: <strong>8734573</strong></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                 <div class="pull-right">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="validated" value="yes" />
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```